# Why doesn't RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke show up on my Visual Studio debugger callstack?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Consider the following C# code:

```
class Program
{
    static public void Print(string toPrint)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(toPrint);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type program = typeof(Program);            
        MethodInfo methodInfo = program.GetMethod("Print", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { "a" });
    }
}
```

When I run it in either Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2008 and hit a breakpoint I put inside the "Print" method, I get the following in the callstack window:

> ConsoleApplication4.exe!ConsoleApplication4.Program.Print(string
>   toPrint)
>
> [Native to Managed Transition]
>
> [Managed to Native Transition]
>
> ConsoleApplication4.exe!ConsoleApplication4.Program.Main(string[]
>   args)

Why doesn't `RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke` show up in my callstack? It is a managed method, after all, so why don't I see it as I would expect?

Also, in general, what are the rules here? Which managed methods can I expect to be missing from my callstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the method isn't actually a managed method. `RunTimeMethodInfo.Invoke` will eventually resolve down to `RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast` which is marked as an `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`. This means the call is actually implemented as a helper directly in the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

In terms of general rules for what won't show up in your call stack:

- If you have `Just My Code` enabled (which is the default) pretty much anything you didn't write will show up as `[External Code]` on the call stack.
- If you are debugging managed only then you'll probably end up seeing a lot of `Native to Managed` and `Managed to Native` transitions on the call stack.
- When dealing with internally implemented methods, you'll also see a bit of fuzziness on the call stack.
- I'm not sure on the exact rules for `DebuggerHidden`, especially when combined with 'just my code' methods, but I wouldn't necessary expect them to show up on the call stack.

If you want to see the raw call stack in all of its glory then you'll need to do the following.

- Debug with both managed and native debugging enabled
- Disable `Just My Code`

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean exactly by "resolve down to"? "Invoke" and "InvokeMethodFast" are not marked MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, only "_InvokeMethodFast" is: I can see their code in Reflector.

Comment: @Omer by that I mean eventually the `_InvokeMethodFast` will be the call made.  Everything between `Invoke` and `_InvokeMethodFast` is both `DebuggerHidden` and likely excluded because of `Just My Code` being enabled.  I updated my answer for ways to get a more complete call stack

Comment: for completeness - According to [this blog post summarizing the effects of the DebuggerXAttributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevejs/archive/2005/12/03/499803.aspx) and my own test, `DebuggerHidden` methods will not show up on the callstack regardless of "Just My Code".

Comment: @Omer that's what I suspected but I wasn't sure. Not sure how I feel about that though. It's often critical to have the 100% correct call stack when tracking down bugs.